# Performance of javascript Class definitions vs Objects

Tags: javascript, performance, class, prototype

I'm writing a javascript application that extensively uses a particular form of dataset, like

```
{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', quz: { baz : 'baz' }}
```

It's only data, but it's nested. There is no static data.

I want to create a template for that dataset to keep the code clean. I can either put a template object somewhere and clone that everytime, like (using jquery just for the example)

```
var ds = jQuery.extend(true, {}, config.dataset);
```

or I can create a 'Class' or function prototype that I can call with

```
var ds = new Dataset();
```

What performs best ? If using the `new` constructor, is there a difference between a Class and a function definition ?

Comment: There is nothing called class in js

Comment: @user2181397 wat? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @user2181397 and aside from that reasonably new addition, you can do a similar thing with an old fashioned function. Not a class, but you can still `new` it to create an instance.

Comment: @user2181397: Yes, there is. And the term has always been used in a "lower case" form for constructors with associated prototypes.

Comment: What aspect of performance? Creation of instances or calling of methods on the object?

Comment: JavaScript classes are introduced in ECMAScript 6 and are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.      ..... Thanks to mdn & you ... learnt something new

Comment: @user2181397—well, javascript still doesn't have "classes" in a classic OO sense. It has a syntax that uses the *class* keyword that does exactly what a constructor does.

Comment: @RobG - creating instances, there are no methods on the object

Comment: go with [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties#Syntax) and have each nesting as its own subclass. no need for a constructor or prototype manipulation; performance with any method shouldn't be a concern; and I wouldn't introduce jquery just for this...

Comment: Of course, coming back to my own question in 2021, I would answer 'use Typescript'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by TJCrowder's answer here, I came up with a third option

```
function newDataset( return { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', quz: { baz : 'baz' }});
var ds = newDataset();
```

- it centralizes the definition of the dataset, which was the purpose
- it always creates a new object, without the risk of sharing data
  members
- i can always change the internal mechanics later and
  benchmark that

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, not only the two you specified, you can also use pure JS prototypes, when comparing all three it seems pure js would be the fastest.

Few things:

1. Please note that using Classes is ES6 which is not widely supported by all browsers yet.
2. The old "new" is called prototypical inheritance, if you use that (which I would suggest you do, or the new format of it using Object.create) be careful of sharing data members between classes.
3. You can also just clone the object with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(firstValueObject));`
4. If you choose Object.create (ES5) you can define default values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-create-vs-pure-js-function/3

Comment: *"The old "new" is called prototypical inheritance"* So is the new one.

Comment: *"You can also just clone the object with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(firstValueObject));"* Not if it has anything on it that JSON doesn't support, like Dates or various other objects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "What performs best?", in general, is: Worry about it **if and when** you actually have a performance problem.

The answer to "What performs best?" in JavaScript is:

1. See the general answer, and
2. *It depends,* test on your target JavaScript engines (browsers, etc.)

Let's ignore performance, though, and look at the alternatives you gave.

Implementing a `DataSet` "class" (constructor and associated prototype, either with the new or old syntax) would be quite complicated and give you virtually no benefit for the use case you describe. You have a nested object structure:

```
{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', quz: { baz : 'baz' }}
```

...and so if you used that as a prototype, it would be **very** easy to get cross-talk between instances. Example:

```js
// Demonstrating cross-talk
function DataSet() {
}
DataSet.prototype = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', quz: { baz : 'baz' }};

var d1 = new DataSet();
var d2 = new DataSet();
d1.quz.baz = "updated";
document.body.innerHTML = d2.quz.baz; // "updated" - huh?!
```

To avoid that, you'd have to make a copy of the `quz` property on construction:

```
function DataSet() {
    this.quz = jQuery.extend(true, {}, this.quz);
}
```

Then you have to remember to do that any time you add new nested objects in the prototype.

From what you've told us, the simplest solution is just to use your first example with `jQuery.extend`.

Comment: actually I suspect the jQuery.extend would be the slowest of them all.

Comment: @DoryZidon: Again, it doesn't matter, and in the rare case where it matters, the answer is *test it*. Also, slowest in what way? Creating instances? Possibly, in theory, not that it will matter. Accessing properties? The result of `extend` will be faster, in theory, not that it will matter, because it doesn't have to work through the prototype chain to find the properties.

Comment: huh indeed ! I would would have fallen in that trap.

Comment: I can only properly benchmark it when its done. I want to make a choice while building it. But perhaps I shouldn't, and abstract it away anyway. Something like `var ds = getNewDataset()`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree that performance isn't always the main concern, and in most cases it doesn't matter, however he did ask about performance more than anything :) Maybe in his particular case it does matter. not sure. Either way properties via the prototype chain is not the recommended way to go about it..I suspect parse strigify would work create as it sounds like default values / or Object.create with defaults.

Comment: @commonpike: Yeah, I would definitely use a factory function so you can easily change it later.